# Modification refusée par moi, mais acceptée à la fin

Tags: support, suggested-edits, review, moderation

[Pour cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/posts/18657/revisions), j'ai refusé la modification (version 2), car je croyais que c'était une injuste révision de l'opinion de l'auteur quant à la description de la particularité du français décrit. Maintenant que la modification a été acceptée par deux membres, quelles sont mes droits, ou que s'attend-on que je ne fasse pas? Ai-je le droit de réviser la version proposée, attendu que mon vote déclarait déjà mon désaccord et qu'on l'a supplanté? Ou bien sera-t-il encore correct pour moi de modifier le tout?

Comment: Au temps pour moi. si je me souviens bien je fais partie des personnes qui ont accepté la modif mais je n'avais pas lu ce que les autres avaient dit avant (c'est vilain je sais). J'assume, j'ai fait un rollback, je présente  mes excuses à  @Mistalis et tu peux repartir de là et agir ou non en conséquences.

Comment: Ça règle à peu près cette situation en particulier. Il demeurerait intéressant d'avoir quelques avis sur la marche à suivre, si ça se reproduisait sur un autre sujet. On pourrait penser à quelque chose comme [ceci](https://french.stackexchange.com/posts/23803/revisions).

Comment: Difficile de prévoir une règle générale car souvent les situations sont différentes. Ici j'ai fait une boulette en ne lisant pas ce que tu avis écrit. Les raisons de refuser une modif peuvent être très variées.

Comment: Bah! Je viens juste de commettre la même insulte à votre égard... J'imagine qu'il y a un endroit pour vérifier les votes déjà donnés, mais je suis passé dessus sans même le remarquer, et ai dû me rendre compte que vous aviez déjà voté contre une fois que j'ai eu accepté. Mes excuses.

Comment: LOL...  je n'arrive pas à retrouver où quelqu'un a fait la remarque (sur meta je crois), que j'ai trouvée juste et donc appliquée, que si on corrige les fautes des non francophones on a du mal à ajuster le niveau de sa réponse. Et par ailleurs qu'ils se corrigent eux-mêmes leurs erreurs, ne peut que les faire progresser s'ils sont motivés. Certains apprécient en effet et corrigent tout de suite, d'autres ne prennent jamais la peine de revenir....

Comment: Et pourtant, dans le cas d'une réponse (plutôt que d'une question), la mise à niveau de la langue me semblerait plus souhaitable qu'un déluge de votes négatifs qui reléguerait possiblement des remarques intéressantes au statut de message de troll. Encore là, la prudence [est de mise](https://french.stackexchange.com/posts/16965/revisions).

Comment: Je parlais des questions. Pour ce qui est des réponses j'imagine mal quelqu'un faisant une réponse acceptable faire beaucoup de fautes de français...  ou alors ce sont des étourderies ou des typos effectivement à corriger.

Answer (score 2):

Je vais tenter une analogie hasardeuse avec Stack Overflow:

La règle sur Stack Overflow est de ne jamais corriger le code, le texte en Français ici, dans une question. Il est recommandé de confirmer ou infirmer que cela est la cause du problème (l’incompréhension ici) par le biais d'un commentaire. Une fois le fait éclairci avec l'auteur il est bon de guider l'auteur pour qu'il édite de lui même.

Editer une question se fait généralement pour reformuler une réflexion autour du problème ou ré-organiser le titre pour qu'il soit plus direct.

Dans le cas des réponses, il est d'usage sur le réseau Stack Exchange de laisser une commentaire lorsque cela touche au cœur de la réponse, les corrections d'erreur typographiques simples sont à corriger.

En bref: si l'erreur a la moindre chance d'être la cause de la question, il ne faut pas y toucher.

Comment: Ceci semble tout à fait logique - à mon humble avis.